# How to make Postgres fail when a query would result in a table scan

Tags: postgresql

We use Postgres as our database, and I'd like the following behaviour:

A setting which we can enable on CI and developer machines, that would cause all queries to fail if they would result in a table scan.

Justification: None of our queries would ever intentionally do this, but occasionally it happens because of a bug in the schema or query. We'd like to catch this much faster, as during development or tests the dataset is small enough that this might not be noticed, but in production would be slow enough to cause significant problems.

Does such a setting exist and if so, how to we enable it?

Comment: A table scan is not necessarily a bad thing. There are many situations where doing that is more efficient than other options - **especially** if you are testing with small (unrealistic) datasets Treating that as an error condition is the wrong approach to pro-actively deal performance problems.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name is there a better way to trigger errors if I've not used an index correctly?

Comment: Define "not used correctly". I think you are approaching this from the wrong end. Your goal is to get a good performance. Focusing on certain steps in the execution plan is the wrong thing to do. You need to measure the actual performance. For that you need to first have a **realistic** data set (in terms of size _and_ data distribution). Then run load tests on your application and make Postgres log every query that runs for more than a specified threshold e.g. 150ms. Then investigate the reason for the slow queries.

Answer (score 0):

On a database with small tables, you will see different execution plans and many more sequential scans, because that is efficient for small tables. So checking for sequential scans on your small test database won't get you anywhere.

The best you can do is to run that test on a database of realistic dimensions and set `statement_timeout` to a small value, so that all statements that run longer than that cause an error.

The only way to actually make a sequential scan fail is the following:

- You create the table and insert a couple of hundred rows of fake data.
- Then you insert your real test data.
- Now delete the fake data and run `VACUUM`. At this point, no index entry will point to the first table block.
- Stop the database server and write garbage (not zeros!) over the first table block, then restart the server.

After that, a sequential scan will fail with a nasty error message.

This method has the downside that it requires manipulation of the data files. Furthermore, autovacuum on the table will fail with the same problem, so at some point your database will go down because transaction ID wraparound is approaching. But it will work the way you want for a while.

I personally think that `statement_timeout` is the better method, because that addresses the real problem. There is nothing evil about a sequential scan as such.

Comment: It makes sense that the execution plan would be different. Is there a better way to get errors if you accidentally query something that doesn't have an index it can use? The statement_timeout approach is quite similar to what we do now but as you can imagine it's quite flaky.

Comment: I think `statement_timeout` is actually the better method, because it is long execution time that is the problem, not sequential scans. You will never get a satisfactory test result unless you test with realistic amounts of data.